# How to compare two strings in a Boolean function

Tags: c++, string, function, boolean, compare

**The following is from a project description for a class:**

"You know that the == operator can be used to test if two string objects are equal.  However, you will recall that they are not considered equal, even when they hold the exact same letters, if the cases of any letters are different.  So, for example, if name1 = "Jack" and name2 = "JACK", they are not considered the same.  Write a program that asks the user to enter two names and stores them in string objects.   It should then report whether or not, ignoring case, they are the same.

To help the program accomplish this task, it should use two functions in addition to main, upperCaseIt( ) and sameString( ).  Here are their function headers:

```
        string upperCaseIt(string s)
        boolean sameString (string s1, string s2)
```

The sameString function, which receives the two strings to be compared, will need to call upperCaseIt for each of them before testing if they are the same.   The upperCaseIt function should use a loop so that it can call the toupper function for every character in the string it receives before returning it back to the sameString function."

**Here is my code:**

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqAIn.png)

What do I need to do for the Boolean to compare n1 and n2 in order to determine whether or not they are equal?

Comment: You should paste the code here instead of using a printscreen.

Comment: How would you compare two `int`'s?  It is the same for `std::string`.

Comment: Also, in `sameString()`, you you use `=` operator instead of `==`.

Comment: Please, don't post code as image. You should edit the question and copy the code (with appropriate formatting) into the text. Hint: The **{}** icon in the toolbar can be used to format a selected text as source code.

Comment: First of all, you need to learn how to follow instructions. It should be `string upperCaseIt(string s)`, not `void upperCaseIt(string& s)`, and the description says "the `==` operator can be used to test if two string objects are equal".

Comment: Resolved the issue. Forgot to use "==" operator.

Answer (score 0):

The gist of this problem is that you want to perform a case-insensitive comparison of two strings. The hints that have been given are pointing the way:

```
bool sameString (string s1, string s2)
{
    return upperCaseIt(s1) == upperCaseIt(s2);
}
```

So by comparing an ALL CAPS version of the two strings, any case differences are lost.